# Two canvases on one page p5.js

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, p5.js

I'm trying to add two canvases to one web page. Want I want is to have a canvas for the mobile view and another canvas for the desktop view. I'm using the p5.js library.

I've managed to use media queries and css to show only the mobile canvas - although the desktop canvas is nowhere to be seen.

Here's what scripts are included in the head:

```
<script src="sketches/memoriesMainPage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="sketches/memoriesColorRoad.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've given each sketch a class in their specific script, inside the setup() function - memoriesMainPage.js:

```
canvas.class("mainSketch");
```

The mobile sketch - memoriesColorRoad.js:

```
canvas.class("phoneSketch");
```

The CSS:

```
.mainSketch {
  display: block;
 }
.phoneSketch {
  display: none;
 }

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  .phoneSketch {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

The code above work for the mobile view. The default canvas is always the phoneSketch, the mainSketch is nowhere to be found when I inspect the page on Google Inspect.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that we can actually run, or better yet a JSFiddle or a CodePen running your CSS? Note that you should get this working with two `div` tags before bothering with the P5.js canvas.

Comment: It looks strange to generate 2 canvas, may be you should first detect the device type, and then generate a canvas adapted to it.

Comment: Its two animations, one built for the mobile and one designed for a desktop window. Nothing strange about it.

Answer (score 1):

are you using p5 instance mode ?, I believe you are overwriting your canvases, that's why you only see one of them, please take a look to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su792jEauZg&t=765s